# ScalaFX : How to stretch ScrollPane to fit its parent

Tags: javafx, scalafx

I use the [Border Pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html) as a layout. The bottom child has a ScrollPane, which should use the complete width (stretch) of the Border Pane - regardless of its content.

```
val scrollPane = new ScrollPane() {
hbarPolicy = ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS
content = new TextFlow() {
  children.add(new Text("Hello World"))
}
}

stage = new PrimaryStage {
title = "ScalaFX Hello World"
width = 1024
height = 768
scene = new Scene {
  content = new BorderPane() {
    center = Label("This is my center text")
    bottom = new Pane {
      children.add(scrollPane)
    }
  }
}
```

It looks during runtime the following way:

[image: During Runtime]

Any chance I can achieve this without manually setting the width of the ScrollPane ?

Comment: It should by default take the complete width of the BorderPane. Please add some code for us to verify your use case.

Comment: Done. The example is in Scala but I think only the hierarchy of the tree is important. I've missed in the original description that I have a Pane in between (in the real project necessary). This seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ScalaFX, unless a parent is passed, Scene is instantiated with an empty Group.

```
class Scene(override val delegate: jfxs.Scene = new jfxs.Scene(new jfxs.Group()))
```

So, instead of setting `content`, set the `root` of the Scene.

```
scene = new Scene {
    root = new BorderPane() {
    center = Label("This is my center text")
    bottom = scrollPane
  }
}
```

You must have noticed that I even removed the *new Pane* that you were adding to bottom before adding the ScrollPane.

***MCVE***

```
import scalafx.application.JFXApp
import scalafx.scene.Scene
import scalafx.scene.control.ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy
import scalafx.scene.control.{Label, ScrollPane}
import scalafx.scene.layout.BorderPane
import scalafx.scene.text.{Text, TextFlow}

object Main extends JFXApp {

  val scrollPane = new ScrollPane() {
    hbarPolicy = ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS
    content = new TextFlow() {
      children.add(new Text("Hello World"))
    }
  }
  stage = new JFXApp.PrimaryStage {
    title.value = "Hello Stage"
    width = 200
    height = 150
    scene = new Scene {
        root = new BorderPane() {
        center = Label("This is my center text")
        bottom = scrollPane
      }
    }
  }
}
```

***Screenshot***

[image]

Comment: Hm...I see no difference. Without the extra new Pane I have no issue at all. I need that pane since in my real project I have a small UI framework, which generates them

Comment: @Hawk66 Added a MCVE and a screenshot